# Google App Engine Java low level Datastore API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

Python's low level Datastore API provides possibilities to set typed properties. (like "setStringProperty".

Does Java low level Datastore API provide typed properties aswell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A short answer is no. The [setProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method is taking Object value as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I just use the setProperty with a typed Parameter (one of these: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types)...